# Insert values based on match function for multiple columns.

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. One (data.frame) consists of collected data like so:

```
ID  spouse  DateTime    Activity
A031    0   2/9/14 17:21    92.25
A031    0   2/9/14 17:22    4
A031    0   2/9/14 17:23    0
A031    0   2/9/14 17:24    0.5
```

And the other (time.frame) consists of empty columns where the collected data should go and a DateTime column with the full duration of our data collection period (months long, by minute), like this but much longer.

```
DateTime        ID  spouse Activity
2/9/14 17:21    NA  NA      NA
2/9/14 17:22    NA  NA      NA
2/9/14 17:23    NA  NA      NA
2/9/14 17:24    NA  NA      NA
```

I want to add the values from data.frame for ID, spouse, and activity columns if the DateTime from data.frame matches the DateTime from time.frame. I have only been able to brute force it and write a line for each variable like so:

```
time.frame$ID <- data.frame$ID[match(time.frame$DateTime, data.frame$DateTime)]
time.frame$spouse <- data.frame$spouse[match(time.frame$DateTime, data.frame$DateTime)]
time.frame$Activity <- data.frame$Activity[match(time.frame$DateTime, data.frame$DateTime)]
```

but I want to know if there is a way to simplify or apply this to a list of column names.  I have many other data.frames I need to do this with and they have many more than 3 columns. I have tried many iterations of lapply but can't get the output I desire (mostly get returned errors).

Comment: `merge` or `dplyr::join`?

Comment: While merge has been useful at other points in this project, when used, it eliminates any row without matching values in the final version. I want to KEEP everything in time.frame and only add to it when data.frame matches.

Comment: `dplyr::full_join` should keep all records even without matches

Comment: Wow! Really helpful insight!